# Which is faster for checking, sql/database query or file_get_content?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, file-get-contents, database-performance

I have this type of data which i call `ids`

I have **8.6M** of these `ids` which i use for "validity" check.

```
tt9916820
tt9916822
tt9916824
tt9916826
```

I was wondering which would be **better** & **faster**?

Using file_get_contents() like this:

```php
$imdbid = $_GET['id'];
if (strpos(file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1/ids.txt"),$imdbid) !== false) {
    echo 'valid id';
} else {
    echo 'invalid id';
}
```

or **if i should just import all the 8.6M+ ids to my database and use sql query like this:**

```php
$imdbid = $_GET['id'];
$existing = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) from wp_postmeta where dbids='$imdbid'");
if ($existing) {
    echo 'valid id';
} else {
    echo 'invalid id';
}
```

Which one would be faster?

Im newbie, if there are any and any better ways of doing this, please let me know as i wanted to learn more. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? How did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a suitable `INDEX`, the database can discover whether a given value is in the table, and do it in a few *milliseconds*.

Searching a file with 8.6 million rows (perhaps 86MB in your example) will *seconds*, maybe even *minutes*.  Furthermore, your suggested code will need room to hold that entire 86MB between fetching and searching.

And, with `strpos`, if the ids are variable length, you could get a spurious match.  For example, searching for "tt9916822" will get 3 hits, none of which are successful.  The database solution will prevent this.

```
tt9916824
tt9916826
tt99168220
tt99168221
tt99168222
```

Comment: `if the ids are variable length, you could get a spurious match. For example, searching for "tt9916822" will get 3 hits, none of which are successful. The database solution will prevent this.`  Now this settle my choice of going with database. Perhaps you  can link me somewhere i can read and learn about index and how to do it properly? Also i'll be doing changes to it, maybe weekly but only to insert new lines of ids, There should be no problem on doing it right ?

Comment: There is not enough space here to tell you how to build your first table in a database, but I will give you some tips.  Because of how simple the table is, use `LOAD DATA ...` to populate it.  If you need to read the table during the weekly update, load the data into a new table, then use `RENAME TABLE` to swap it into place.

Answer (score 1):

If the file does not change often then you should import it into a table and create an index on the column you want to search on. A query on an indexed column should be ***much*** faster than:

1. fetching an 8MB (86MB?) file over the wire
2. loading all of it into memory (php has a memory limit)
3. searching it using `strpos` (which only stops if it finds a match or reaches the end of string)
4. only to find that the value being searched does not exist

Comment: Hello, Im planning to do changes on the file maybe weekly but only to add new lines of ids at the very bottom/last. Query it still very much suitable for it right?

Comment: MySQL can import data from txt files -and- it allows you to write queries that can insert data ignoring duplicates so the order in which you write data to file doesn't matter.